# MongoDB - Find all the records from another table

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have the following two tables :

**Comments :**

```
{
        "createdOn": "2020-03-08T04:19:20.276Z",
        "comment": "First comment in the app",
        "likesCount": 1,
        "_id": "5e6472c32fe18a59b1068f46",
        "userId": "5e60ec371dc3d30e61c6805b",
        "postId": "5e6356546d284c2cdfe1ad92",
        "__v": 0
    }
```

**CommentLikes** :

```
{
        "createdOn": "2020-03-08T06:47:58.855Z",
        "_id": "5e64955abb6056610f802159",
        "userId": "5e60ec371dc3d30e61c6805b",
        "commentId": "5e6472c32fe18a59b1068f46",
        "__v": 0
    }
```

Now i am trying to get all the likes with following query :-

```
Comments.aggregate([
    {$match: {postId : postId}},
    {$lookup:{
        from: 'commentLikes',
        localField: '_id',
        foreignField: 'commentId',
        as : 'likes'
    }}
    ])
.exec()
```

It is not returning any like. Response I get from this query is :-

```
{
        "_id": "5e6472c32fe18a59b1068f46",
        "createdOn": "2020-03-08T04:19:20.276Z",
        "comment": "First comment in the app",
        "likesCount": 1,
        "userId": "5e60ec371dc3d30e61c6805b",
        "postId": "5e6356546d284c2cdfe1ad92",
        "__v": 0,
        "likes": []
    }
```

Don't know what I am doing wrong here. Please help.

Comment: Your query seems ok, Did you check if you're providing collection name correctly & also type of `_id` matches with `commenId`? I guess types miss-match is the issue, you need to convert one to another form !!

Comment: Your aggregate query seems to work. https://mongoplayground.net/p/nluCvcQclF1 
Are you sure your commentLikes document's physical document name is `commentLikes ` ?

Answer (score 1):

When everybody said that query is okay and the problem should be in the name of collection. Then I try to get the list of my collections with following code:-

```
mongoose.connection.on('open', function (ref) {
console.log('Connected to mongo server.');
//trying to get collection names
mongoose.connection.db.listCollections().toArray(function (err, names) {
    console.log(names); // [{ name: 'dbname.myCollection' }]
    module.exports.Collection = names;
});})
```

And i was surprised that mongoose changed the name of all the collections to small letters. Collection name **commentLikes** became **commentlikes**. Now my query is working good.

Comment: That's default behavior of mongoose & also how you do your schemas, which you need know while using mongoose schemas !! So sad part in here is you've been working with only the code, without executing your queries directly on DB or not even having a look at your DB even when everyone suggested to do for !!

Answer (score 0):

If type of `_id` field in comments collection is of type `ObjectId()` &  if `commentId` in commentLikes collection is a string then, Try below query :

```
Comments.aggregate([
    { $match: { postId: postId } },
    {
        $lookup:
        {
            from: "commentLikes",
            let: { id: { $toString: "$_id" } }, // Convert ObjectId() to string to match with type of commentId(string)
            pipeline: [
                {
                    $match:
                    {
                        $expr:
                            { $eq: ["$$id", "$commentId"] }
                    }
                }
            ],
            as: "likes"
        }
    }
])
    .exec()
```

**Test :** [MongoDB-Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/S7xEU3AFAjg)

Comment: commentId in CommentLikes is also mongoose.Types.ObjectId();

Comment: @gouravsarswa : then is that name of collection issue ?

Comment: I have already checked the name of collection many times. According to me everything is right. But not getting data. Don't know why.

Comment: @-whoami mongodb version i am using is 3.5.4. and mongoose 5.9.3

Comment: @gouravsarswa : not sure why, maybe I'm missing something, but I think there shouldn't be any reason this query fails, anyhow above answer would not work for you on `3.5` !! lastly if these two collections on same db then there is nothing that can fail this !

Comment: @-whoami I tried it with other collections and it is not working for any.

Comment: @-whoami Thank you for your help.